# Im trying to change the color of my font based on if it is an "X" or an "O" but all colors keep changing?

Tags: reactjs

My colors keep changing from green to red but I want each color to stay based on if "X" or "O" is put down.

```
const Square = (props) => {
    return (
        <button
            className="square"
            onClick={props.onClickEvent}
            style={{ color: props.active ? "green" : "red" }}
        >
            {props.value}
        </button>
    );
};

const Board = () => {
    const initialSquares = Array(9).fill(null);
    const [squares, setSquares] = useState(initialSquares);
    const [xIsNext, setXIsNext] = useState(true);

    const handleClickEvent = (i) => {
        const newSquares = [...squares];

        const winnerDeclared = Boolean(calculateWinner(newSquares));
        const squareFilled = Boolean(newSquares[i]);
        if (winnerDeclared || squareFilled) {
            return;
        }

        newSquares[i] = xIsNext ? "X" : "O";
        setSquares(newSquares);
        setXIsNext(!xIsNext);
    };

    const renderSquare = (i) => {
        return (
            <Square
                value={squares[i]}
                onClickEvent={() => handleClickEvent(i)}
                active={xIsNext}
            />
        );
    };

    const winner = calculateWinner(squares);
    const status = winner
        ? `Winner: ${winner}`
        : `Next player: ${xIsNext ? "X" : "O"}`;

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="status">{status}</div>
            <div className="board-row">
                {renderSquare(0)}
                {renderSquare(1)}
                {renderSquare(2)}
            </div>
            <div className="board-row">
                {renderSquare(3)}
                {renderSquare(4)}
                {renderSquare(5)}
            </div>
            <div className="board-row">
                {renderSquare(6)}
                {renderSquare(7)}
                {renderSquare(8)}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

const Game = () => {
    return (
        <div className="game">
            Tic-Tac-Toe
            <Board />
        </div>
    );
};

function calculateWinner(squares) {
    const lines = [
        [0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5],
        [6, 7, 8], // rows
        [0, 3, 6],
        [1, 4, 7],
        [2, 5, 8], // columns
        [0, 4, 8],
        [2, 4, 6], // diagonals
    ];

    for (let line of lines) {
        const [a, b, c] = line;

        if (
            squares[a] &&
            squares[a] === squares[b] &&
            squares[a] === squares[c]
        ) {
            return squares[a]; // "X" or "O"
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

The first "X" I put is green and then when I put an "O" the "O" and "X" both turn red, this keeps repeating every time I put an "X" or "O". I am trying to use the same method for switching from and "X" to an "O" to switch the color of the text and stay that color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution would be to check the value instad of the active prop.

```
const Square = (props) => {
    return (
        <button
            className="square"
            onClick={props.onClickEvent}
            style={{ color: props.value===“X” ? "green" : "red" }}
        >
            {props.value}
        </button>
    );
};
```

Also try to add “x” and “y” keys fot square elements.

Comment: That just keeps all the text color to Red :(, I will share the full page of code and maybe that will help.